# Convert View to Bitmap (OutOfMemoryException)

Tags: android, kotlin, view, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have a Bitmap created from a View with the kotlin extesion *drawToBitmamp()*. It works fine in most cases, but in low end devices, it throws an OutOfMemoryException.

I've been doing research about how to handle Bitmaps efficiently, but I found nothing when it comes to bitmaps generated from View's. Does anyone know how to avoid that exception while handling it better?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to add

android:largeHeap="true" in application tag in manifest

and also add below line

dexOptions{ javaMaxHeapSize "4g" }

in app level gradle or jvmargs=-Xmx2048M

Hope it may help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it didn't help. The project already has jvmargs=-Xmx4096M and the dexOptions set. So I set the largeHeap, but I'm still getting the crash.

Comment: Can u send or update ur code where you are creating bitmap so it will be more helpful for us.

Comment: Also please check here if your requirement match with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68393893/4042384

Comment: Also Please read it to manage this type of issue from here...hope may help you https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap